How to add extras to a gltf\glb file using glTFLoader by KhronosGroup?
I'm tring to add "extras", custom metadata, to a gltf\glb file using glTFLoader by KhronosGroup
https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/blob/main/specification/2.0/README.md#reference-extras
I open the model file than I parse all the nodes (or mesh or wheatever) and I try to add extras, in different formats (ie Dictionary(of String, String), but the result is always empty extras properties  ("extras" : {})
Dim GLTFSchema As glTFLoader.Schema.Gltf = glTFLoader.Interface.LoadModel(GLTFFilename)
For Each myNode As glTFLoader.Schema.Node In GLTFSchema.Nodes
 myNode.Extras = ???
Next


I don't know if it's possible with the Khronos one, but I know that vpenades' SharpGLTF can do this and save a new glTF / GLB file. https://github.com/vpenades/SharpGLTF
